# DolphinDB: how to quickly calculate the correlation of a column with the other columns in a table?

Tags: correlation, dolphindb, multicol

Suppose there is a table containing a column “x“ and the other 10 columns from “y1“ to “y10“. I want to calculate the correlation of column “x“ with the other 10 columns. Is there an easy way to achieve this in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `each-` higher-order functions (e.g., `each`, `eachLeft`, `eachPre`) to iterate over columns “y1“, “y2“…, and “y10“. The following script uses the `:R / eachRight` function with the `corr` function to calculate the correlation of column "x" with the other columns.

```
corr:R(table.x. table[`y1`y2...]）
```